# Adding markers and display the tooltip in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, hover, plotly

The following R code creates a line plot with markers. I wish to create a plot such that when hover is performed on the marker, it gives the "digits" and "sepw" values in the tooltip. Also the marker should be bold. Please help.

```
 digits = 1:150
 sep = iris$Sepal.Length
 sepw = iris$Sepal.Width
 plot_f1 <-  ggplot(iris, aes(x = digits)) + 
 geom_line(aes(y = sep, color = "red", label = sepw )) + geom_point(y = sep)
 plot_f1 = ggplotly(plot_f1)
 plot_f1
```

Comment: YOu can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917101/how-do-i-show-the-y-value-on-tooltip-while-hover-in-ggplot2)

Comment: just `ggplotly(plot_f1, tooltip = c("x","label"))` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first solution for your problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

digits = 1:150
sep = iris$Sepal.Length
sepw = iris$Sepal.Width
plot_f1 <-  ggplot(iris, aes(x=digits, y=sep, label=sepw)) + 
            geom_line(color="red") + geom_point()
plot_f1 <- ggplotly(plot_f1, tooltip=c("x","label"))
plot_f1
```

[image]

A second solution is based on the `text` aesthetic:

```
plot_f2 <-  ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=digits, y=sep, group=1, 
                   text=paste("Sepw =",sepw,"<br />Digits =",digits))) + 
            geom_line(color="red") + geom_point()
plot_f2 <- ggplotly(plot_f2, tooltip="text")
plot_f2
```

[image]