# Any way to display data frame information besides x and y on hover with shiny/ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(6,7,8,9,10), z=c('a','b','c','d','e'))
> df
  x  y z
1 1  6 a
2 2  7 b
3 3  8 c
4 4  9 d
5 5 10 e

ggplot(df,
  aes(x=x, y=y)+
  geom_point()
```

Let's say I have a data frame with columns x, y, and z. I create a ggplot with x along the x axis and y along the y axis. I've seen [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917101/how-do-i-show-the-y-value-on-tooltip-while-hover-in-ggplot2) of hover code that displays the x and y values when hovering over a point, but is it possible to access other data in the data frame besides what's graphed along x and y? For example if someone hovers over point (1,6), is there a way to display 'a'?

Comment: lookup https://plot.ly and http://jkunst.com/highcharter/

Comment: what about ggvis? and the movie Explorer example on the Shiny Gallery, https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/051-movie-explorer/server.R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code based on the `plotly` package:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), y=c(6,7,8,9,10), z=c('a','b','c','d','e'))

library(ggplot2)
# Define the content and format of the tooltip in the "text" aesthetic
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, 
           text=paste("X=",x,"<br>Y=",y,"<br>Z=",z))) + 
geom_point()

library(plotly)
p <- ggplotly(p, tooltip="text")
print(p)
```

[image]