# How to add custom hover function to plotOutput so it can be used for many plots

Tags: javascript, r, ggplot2, shiny, hover

I'm experimenting with some code for hover messages on top of ggplot2 objects, 
and so far it is working quite well, except now the following challenge goes beyond my skills I fear:

In an App where I will have about 6 to 72 similar ggplots spread over various pages in my app, I would like to be able to attach the hover javascript to all of them automatically: i.e. change from a single tags$script to a generic solution that works for all plots

I tried to build a new plotOutput2 function but I can't get it to work at all.

```
plotOutput2 <- function(outputId, width = "100%", height = "400px", click = NULL, 
                        dblclick = NULL, hover = NULL, hoverDelay = NULL, hoverDelayType = NULL, 
                        brush = NULL, clickId = NULL, hoverId = NULL, inline = FALSE,
                        onhover) {
    input <- plotOutput(outputId, width, height, click, dblclick, 
                         hover, hoverDelay, hoverDelayType, brush, clickId, hoverId, inline)
    attribs <- c(input$children[[2]]$attribs, onhover = onhover)
    input$children[[2]]$attribs <- attribs
    input
}
```

but I get an error that says:

> input$children[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

The idea is to then call this:

```
plotOutput2("ploty", hover = hoverOpts(id = "ploty_hover", delay = 0), onhover = "hoverJS(this.id)"),
```

and the javascript (unfinished) needs to look something like this but create unique output ids instead of `#my_tooltip` that contain the `plotname + tooltip`: i.e.: `#distPlot_tooltip`

```
hoverjs <- c(
  "function hoverJS(id){",
  "document.getElementById(id).mousemove(function(e) {", 
  "$('#my_tooltip').show();",
  "$('#my_tooltip').css({",             
  "top: (e.pageY + 5) + 'px',",             
  "left: (e.pageX + 5) + 'px'",         
  "});",     
  "});",   
  "}"
)
```

with  the following line in the UI

```
tags$script(HTML(hoverjs)),  ## to add the javascript to the app
```

The app with only a single precoded javascript hover popup for one plot (top one of the two) looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
# put function plotOutput2 here
# put hoverJS code here 

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(tags$style('
     #my_tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      width: 300px;
      z-index: 100;
      padding: 0;
     }
  ')),

  tags$script('
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // id of the plot
      $("#ploty").mousemove(function(e) { 

        // ID of uiOutput
        $("#my_tooltip").show();         
        $("#my_tooltip").css({             
          top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
          left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
        });     
      });     
    });
  '),
  #tags$script(HTML(hoverjs)), 
  selectInput("var_y", "Y-Axis", choices = names(iris)),
  plotOutput("ploty", hover = hoverOpts(id = "ploty_hover", delay = 0)),
  plotOutput("plotx", hover = hoverOpts(id = "plotx_hover", delay = 0)), 
  uiOutput("my_tooltip")


)

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$ploty <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(iris, aes_string("Sepal.Width", input$var_y)) + 
      geom_point()
  })
  output$plotx <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("mpg", 'hp')) + 
      geom_point()
  })
  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$ploty_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$ploty_hover)
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    wellPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("vals"), style = 'background-color:#fff; padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')
  })

  output$vals <- DT::renderDataTable({
    hover <- input$ploty_hover 
    y <- nearPoints(iris, input$ploty_hover)
    req(nrow(y) != 0)
    DT::datatable(t(y), colnames = rep("", ncol(t(y))), options = list(dom = 't', searching = F, bSort = FALSE))
  })  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT based on initial answer:**

I will have (currently) 7 groups of plots in my app, 
each plot name will start with a name identifying the group (each group uses a different data frame): in the example 2 groups: 'FP1Plot' and 'CleanFP1'
The subplots within one group will get a serialnr 
i.e.: 'FP1Plot_1', 'FP1Plot_2', 'CleanFP1_1', 'CleanFP1_2'

I have tried to rewrite the `hovers <- ....` to make it a easily generated list for the possible huge (>100) number of plots, and will look up the needed dataframe in an if statement construction, 
but at this point the hover doesn't react

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
require('shinyjqui')

mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
max_plots <- 12;

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2, sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=5, min=1, max=max_plots),
               h4('click points to see info'),
               h4('select area to zoom'),
               h4('Double click to unzoom')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
#my_tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
}'),
      tags$script('
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=plot]").mousemove(function(e) { 
    $("#my_tooltip").show();         
    $("#my_tooltip").css({             
      top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
      left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
    });     
  });     
});')
    ),

    tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('fp1',
        uiOutput("FP1Plotmultiplots")
      ),
    tabPanel('clean',
      uiOutput("CleanFP1multiplots") 
    )
    ),
    style = 'width:1250px'
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  plotlist <- c('FP1Plot', 'CleanFP1')

  ranges <- reactiveValues()

  # make the individual plots
  observe({
    lapply(1:input$n, function(i){
      plotname <- paste0('FP1Plot', i)
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
          coord_cartesian(xlim =ranges[[paste('FP1Plot', i, 'x', sep = '')]], 
                          ylim = ranges[[paste('FP1Plot', i, 'y', sep = '')]]
          ) +
          theme_classic() +
          theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                legend.position = 'bottom') 
      })
    })
  })

  observe({
    lapply(1:input$n, function(i){
      plotname <- paste0('CleanFP1', i)  
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris, aes(iris[ ,ncol(iris)-1], iris[ ,i], color = as.factor(Species))) + geom_point() +
          coord_cartesian(xlim =ranges[[paste('CleanFP1', i, 'x', sep = '')]], 
                          ylim = ranges[[paste('CleanFP1', i, 'y', sep = '')]]
          ) +
          theme_classic() +
          theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                legend.position = 'bottom') 
      })
    })
  })

  # make the divs with plots and buttons etc  
  lapply(plotlist, function(THEPLOT) { 
  output[[paste(THEPLOT, 'multiplots', sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- list()
    n <- input$n

    n_cols <- if(n == 1) {
      1
    } else if (n %in% c(2,4)) {
      2
    } else if (n %in% c(3,5,6,9)) {
      3
    } else {
      4
    }
    Pwidth <- 900/n_cols
    Pheigth <- 500/ceiling(n/n_cols) # calculate number of rows
    Pwidth2 <- Pwidth+40
    Pheigth2 <-Pheigth+40 

    plot_output_list <- list();

    for(i in 1:input$n) {
      plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
        div(id = paste0('div', THEPLOT, i),
            wellPanel(
              plotOutput(paste0(THEPLOT, i), 
                         width = Pwidth, 
                         height = Pheigth,
                         hover = hoverOpts(id = paste(THEPLOT, i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                         # click = paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_click'),
                         # dblclick =  paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_dblclick'),
                         # brush = brushOpts(
                         #   id =  paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_brush'),
                         #   resetOnNew = TRUE
                         # )
              ), 
              style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheigth2, 'px', sep = '')),
            style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheigth2, 'px', sep = ''))

      ))
    }
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })

  })

  eg <- expand.grid(plotlist, 1:max_plots) 

  tooltipTable <- reactive({

    ## attempt to make this work for the large amount of plots in my app
    hovers <- as.list(sapply(c(sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])), function(key) key = eval(parse(text = paste('input$', key, '_hover', sep = ''))) )) 

    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")
      dataset <- if(grepl('FP1Plot', plotid)) { mtcars } else { iris } 
      ## I will add some code here based on the plot nr to grab the needed columns for the x and y data of the specific plot, since the list of x and y columns will be stored in two vectors:
      ## 1 vector with x parameter 1:12, and 1 for y. 
      ## every group of plots will use the same list of selected x and y parameters 
      # (or if I switch to plot group specific lists, the lists will contain the group names just like the plots, so I can link them by name here)
      y <- nearPoints(dataset, input[[plothoverid]], 
                      threshold = 15)
      if(nrow(y)){
        datatable(t(y), colnames = rep("", nrow(y)), 
                  options = list(dom = 't'))
      }
    }
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(tooltipTable())
    wellPanel(DTOutput("vals"), 
              style = 'background-color:#fff; padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')
  })

  output$vals <- renderDT({
    tooltipTable()
  })  


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the general context, but maybe this can help:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style('
#my_tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
}'),
  tags$script('
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[id^=plot]").mousemove(function(e) { 
    $("#my_tooltip").show();         
    $("#my_tooltip").css({             
      top: (e.pageY + 5) + "px",             
      left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
    });     
  });     
});')
  ),

  selectInput("var_y", "Y-Axis", choices = names(iris)),
  plotOutput("ploty", hover = hoverOpts(id = "ploty_hover", delay = 0)),
  plotOutput("plotx", hover = hoverOpts(id = "plotx_hover", delay = 0)), 
  uiOutput("my_tooltip")
)

datasets <- list(plotx = mtcars, ploty = iris)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$ploty <- renderPlot({
    req(input$var_y)
    ggplot(iris, aes_string("Sepal.Width", input$var_y)) + geom_point()
  })
  output$plotx <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string("mpg", 'hp')) + geom_point()
  })

  tooltipTable <- reactive({
    hovers <- list(plotx = input$plotx_hover, ploty = input$ploty_hover)
    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")
      y <- nearPoints(datasets[[plotid]], input[[plothoverid]], 
                      threshold = 15)
      if(nrow(y)){
        datatable(t(y), colnames = rep("", nrow(y)), 
                  options = list(dom = 't'))
      }
    }
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(tooltipTable())
    wellPanel(DTOutput("vals"), 
              style = 'background-color:#fff; padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')
  })

  output$vals <- renderDT({
    tooltipTable()
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Update

```
require('shiny')
require('ggplot2')
library(DT)

#mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
max_plots <- 12;

ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  sidebarPanel(width = 2, sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=5, min=1, max=max_plots),
               h4('click points to see info'),
               h4('select area to zoom'),
               h4('Double click to unzoom')
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$head(
      tags$style('
                 #my_tooltip {
                 position: absolute;
                 pointer-events:none;
                 width: 300px;
                 z-index: 100;
                 padding: 0;
                 }'),
      tags$script('
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                  setTimeout(function(){
                  $("[id^=FP1Plot],[id^=CleanFP1]").mousemove(function(e) { 
                  $("#my_tooltip").show();         
                  $("#my_tooltip").css({             
                  top: (e.offsetY) + "px",             
                  left: (e.pageX + 5) + "px"         
                  });     
                  });     
                  },5000)});')
    ),

    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('fp1',
               div(style = "position:relative",
                   uiOutput("FP1Plotmultiplots"))
      ),
      tabPanel('clean',
               uiOutput("CleanFP1multiplots") 
      )
    ),
    uiOutput("my_tooltip"),
    style = 'width:1250px'
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  plotlist <- c('FP1Plot', 'CleanFP1')

  ranges <- reactiveValues()

  # make the individual plots
  observe({
    lapply(1:input$n, function(i){
      plotname <- paste0('FP1Plot', i)
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, color = as.factor(cyl))) + geom_point() +
          coord_cartesian(xlim =ranges[[paste('FP1Plot', i, 'x', sep = '')]], 
                          ylim = ranges[[paste('FP1Plot', i, 'y', sep = '')]]
          ) +
          theme_classic() +
          theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                legend.position = 'bottom') 
      })
    })
  })

  observe({
    lapply(1:input$n, function(i){
      plotname <- paste0('CleanFP1', i)  
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        x <- names(iris)[ncol(iris)-1]
        y <- names(iris)[i]
        ggplot(iris, aes_string(x, y, color = "Species")) + geom_point() +
          coord_cartesian(xlim =ranges[[paste('CleanFP1', i, 'x', sep = '')]], 
                          ylim = ranges[[paste('CleanFP1', i, 'y', sep = '')]]
          ) +
          theme_classic() +
          theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12), 
                legend.title=element_blank(),
                legend.position = 'bottom') 
      })
    })
  })

  # make the divs with plots and buttons etc  
  lapply(plotlist, function(THEPLOT) { 
    output[[paste(THEPLOT, 'multiplots', sep = '')]] <- renderUI({
      plot_output_list <- list()
      n <- input$n

      n_cols <- if(n == 1) {
        1
      } else if (n %in% c(2,4)) {
        2
      } else if (n %in% c(3,5,6,9)) {
        3
      } else {
        4
      }
      Pwidth <- 900/n_cols
      Pheigth <- 500/ceiling(n/n_cols) # calculate number of rows
      Pwidth2 <- Pwidth+40
      Pheigth2 <- Pheigth+40 

      plot_output_list <- list();

      for(i in 1:input$n) {
        plot_output_list <- append(plot_output_list,list(
          div(id = paste0('div', THEPLOT, i),
              wellPanel(
                plotOutput(paste0(THEPLOT, i), 
                           width = Pwidth, 
                           height = Pheigth,
                           hover = hoverOpts(id = paste(THEPLOT, i, "hover", sep = '_'), delay = 0)
                           # click = paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_click'),
                           # dblclick =  paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_dblclick'),
                           # brush = brushOpts(
                           #   id =  paste0(THEPLOT, i, '_brush'),
                           #   resetOnNew = TRUE
                           # )
                ), 
                style = paste('border-color:#339fff; border-width:2px; background-color: #fff; width:',  Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheigth2, 'px', sep = '')),
              style = paste('display: inline-block; margin: 2px; width:', Pwidth2, 'px; height:', Pheigth2, 'px', sep = ''))

        ))
      }
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
    })

  })

  eg <- expand.grid(plotlist, 1:max_plots) 
  plotids <- sprintf('%s_%s', eg[,1], eg[,2])
  names(plotids) <- plotids

  tooltipTable <- reactive({
    hovers <- 
      lapply(plotids, function(key) input[[paste0(key, '_hover')]])

    notNull <- sapply(hovers, Negate(is.null))
    if(any(notNull)){
      plotid <- names(which(notNull))
      plothoverid <- paste0(plotid, "_hover")
      dataset <- if(grepl('FP1Plot', plotid)) { mtcars } else { iris } 
      ## I will add some code here based on the plot nr to grab the needed columns for the x and y data of the specific plot, since the list of x and y columns will be stored in two vectors:
      ## 1 vector with x parameter 1:12, and 1 for y. 
      ## every group of plots will use the same list of selected x and y parameters 
      # (or if I switch to plot group specific lists, the lists will contain the group names just like the plots, so I can link them by name here)
      y <- nearPoints(dataset, input[[plothoverid]], 
                      threshold = 15)
      if(nrow(y)){
        datatable(t(y), colnames = rep("", nrow(y)), 
                  options = list(dom = 't'))
      }
    }
  })

  output$my_tooltip <- renderUI({
    req(tooltipTable())
    wellPanel(DTOutput("vals"), 
              style = 'background-color:#fff; padding:10px; width:400px;border-color:#339fff')
  })

  output$vals <- renderDT({
    tooltipTable()
  })  


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hey Stephane, thanks for the try. I played with your answer a bit and I see it would still require to hardcode in advance the hover list and dataset list. 
I don't know in advance how many plots my user will ask for throughout the app, so I was looking for a generic solution that adds the hover to plotoutput  so that whenever one of these plots it is rendered, it will automatically use the correct data frame and hover id

Comment: @Mark Can you show a minimal code with the dynamic number of plots ? Otherwise it's hard to answer.

Comment: ill try to make one when I can, but i'm heading to sea for a week of sampling and don't know when I'll have the chance this week.

Comment: I added a new app that shows the multi plot structure I plan to work out further for my main program

Comment: Very nice stefane! Im now brainstorming on how
 to build a similar structure for the click events but quickly realized that the reactive needs to be quite different as the clicks dont go back to Null values like the hovers do