# Is it possible to show a plot in the hover info using plotly in R?

Tags: r, hover, plotly, tooltip

Suppose I have a plotly graph in which I want to show another plot as hover info. Is it possible using plotly or echart4r? If yes, an example would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not a straightforward solution but this should be achievable using Shiny.

Plotly has the `event_data` function to allow you to access information about the user's interaction with the plot (such as where they are hovering):

https://rdrr.io/cran/plotly/man/event_data.html

https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#shiny-plotly-inputs

You could then tie this to a reactive UI element which contains the plot you are after inside of a tooltip. You will likely need to use a bit of Javascript to move around the tooltip. See example 3 from here for an idea:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38919892/2947600

Give this a go if you'd like and if you're having a hard time, I might have the time to make a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give a try with the information you have given and will revert you.