# Make values to be seen only when hovered

Tags: r, r-plotly

Can we make these values seen only when hovered . Example "Toyota Corolla" to be seen only when hovered. Now all the values are appearing

```
library(plotly)

data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$am == 1 & mtcars$gear == 4),]

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 10))
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations(x = data$wt,
                  y = data$mpg,
                  text = rownames(data),
                  xref = "x",
                  yref = "y",
                  showarrow = TRUE,
                  arrowhead = 4,
                  arrowsize = .5,
                  ax = 20,
                  ay = -40,
                  # Styling annotations' text:
                  font = list(color = '#264E86',
                              family = 'sans serif',
                              size = 14))

fig
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917101/how-do-i-show-the-y-value-on-tooltip-while-hover-in-ggplot2

Comment: Looks like this is ggplots. Not sure if this can be replicated

Answer (score 0):

To add the row names/car types so that they appear when you hover over the point, you just need to add `text` and use it in `hoverinfo`

In your example, you can use `rownames()` to get the car types and add them to `text` which then can be used by `hoverinfo`

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
               marker = list(size = 10), text = rownames(data), hoverinfo = "text")
```

However, if you didn't have the car names as row names and just as a column in a dataframe, you can just apply them directly to `text` which then can be used by `hoverinfo`

```
#Not required. Just used to create a column with car names#
data$cars <- rownames(data)
```

You can then use the new column as `text`

```
fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
               marker = list(size = 10), text = data$cars, hoverinfo = "text")
```

Both methods will give you the following result

[image: example1]